# Shortest self-modifying code to wish a happy New Year!

Tags: code-golf

Your code just has to print "Happy 2013".
However, if it detects that it's 2014, it has to modify itself (as a running process!!) and print "Happy 2014" instead.

By self-modifying I mean the running process must really modify itself: it should alter its own instructions while it is executing.

Shortest code wins.

-10% size bonus if it's general, so it works for 2015, etc.

<sub>Sorry if the task excludes some languages or systems where it's not possible...</sub>

Comment: Please explain what "modify itself (as a running process!!)" means.

Comment: @DavidCarraher : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-modifying_code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Bash / shell script (35 chars - 10% = 31.5)

I think this shell script counts as self-modifying:

```
$ eval "y()(echo Happy `date +%Y`)";y
Happy 2013
$
```

At least, it does modify its own function `y`:

```
$ set | grep -A3 '^y ()'
y () 
{ 
    ( echo Happy 2015 )
}
$
```

---

@manatwork suggested `eval "y()(date +Happy\ %Y)";y`, which produces the desired output, but I'm not sure if this counts as self-modifying, to the extent that it self-modifies with the current year.  The generated function is as follows, which won't be a different function on a yearly basis:

```
y () 
{ 
    ( date +Happy\ %Y )
}
```

If it does count, then the score is:

## Bash / shell script (29 chars - 10% = 26.1)

---

A lot of entries don't seem to make any attempt to self-modify.  If we lift this restriction for shell-script, then we can do this which weighs in at:

## 15 chars - 10% = 13

```
date +Happy\ %Y
```

Comment: Good one, but can be shorter: `eval "y(){ date +Happy\ %Y;}";y`. By the way, please add a heading line (with some kind of formatting) to your post containing language, character count and score.

Comment: Thanks @manatwork - I'm not sure if that counts or not - see my edit.  But thanks for the suggestion.  This is my first answer on PPCG, so my apologies for not getting the score and formatting thing right.

Comment: Ah, you mean, the generated code is also generic, not year-specific. Good point. I thought, as function y not existed before running the code, creating it is a modification. Not sure anymore.

Comment: IMHO defining a function on the fly with `eval` is not self-modification of running code, it's just part of the language.

Answer (score 3):

### PHP

#### Creation of source code statement: 26 - 10% = 23.4

```
eval('?>Happy '.@date(Y));
```

#### Overlay of existing instruction: 255 - 10% = 229.5

This can only possibly work on Linux systems configured with a writable `/proc/self/mem`, and `short_tags = On` is also assumed. (If `short_tags = Off`, replace `<?` with `<?php` , for a score of 233.1.)

```
<?$p='/proc/self/';$f=fopen($p.@mem,'r+');foreach(file($p.@maps)as$L)if(sscanf($L,'%x-%x rw%c',$i,$e,$n)>2)for(fseek($f,$i),$a=@xxxx,$e-=$i-4;$e-=4;){$b=$a;$a=fread($f,4);if($j=@strpos("x$b$a",GO.LF)){fseek($f,$j-9,1);fputs($f,@date(Y));}}$f=0?>Happy GOLF
```

Reformatted for readability:

```
<?
$p = '/proc/self/';
$f = fopen($p . @mem, 'r+');
foreach (file($p . @maps) as $L)
if (sscanf($L, '%x-%x rw%c', $i, $e, $n) > 2)
for (fseek($f, $i), $a = @xxxx, $e -= $i - 4; $e -= 4;) {
    $b = $a;
    $a = fread($f, 4);
    if ($j = @strpos("x$b$a", GO.LF)) {
        fseek($f, $j - 9, /* SEEK_CUR */ 1);
        fputs($f, @date(Y));
    }
}
$f = 0
?>Happy GOLF
```

Comment: +1 This is the only real self-modifying code posted yet!

Answer (score 2):

## APL, self-modifying*, general – 72 chars

Tested on Dyalog APL. On other systems you might have to adjust the `3+` on line 3.

```
∇H
y←2012
→(y=z←1⌷⎕TS)/k
x←⎕CR'H'⋄x[2;3+⍳4]←⍕z
⎕FX x⋄H⋄→0
k:⎕←'Happy'y
∇
```

(*) This function does the following:

- set a variable y to some constant year;
- test whether y points to the current year; if not:

  - update its own definition, changing the numeric constant in the first line so that it sets variable y to the current year;
  - call itself recursively, so that the recursive call uses the new definition.

*Whether this is acceptable as self-modifying, I'll leave to the OP to decide.*

Example invocation, displaying the function code before and after the invocation. As you can see, line 1 has changed during the invocation:

```
      ∇H[⎕]∇
[0]   H
[1]   y←2012
[2]   →(y=z←1⌷⎕TS)/k
[3]   x←⎕CR'H' ⋄ x[2;3+⍳4]←⍕z
[4]   ⎕FX x ⋄ H ⋄ →0
[5]  k:⎕←'Happy'y

      H
 Happy  2013

      ∇H[⎕]∇
[0]   H
[1]   y←2013
[2]   →(y=z←1⌷⎕TS)/k
[3]   x←⎕CR'H' ⋄ x[2;3+⍳4]←⍕z
[4]   ⎕FX x ⋄ H ⋄ →0
[5]  k:⎕←'Happy'y
```

Answer (score 2):

### Forth: 22 / 32 Chars.   ( Using gforth )

```
s" Happy 2022" swap +!              ( 22 chars )
```

A compiled but slightly longer version is shown here,
as the result can be decompiled, and its effects demonstrated.
Principle of operation is identical to the shorter version above.
Consider the longer version as demonstratable proof of concept.

```
: happy s" Happy 2022" swap +! ;    ( 32 chars )
```

I'll decompile this first, then execute, and decompile it again:

```
see happy    ( decompile happy, as it is now )
```

> : happy
> s" Happy 2022" swap +! ;

```
happy   ( execute the self-modifying happy )

see happy ( decompile happy again )
```

> : happy
> s" Rappy 2022" swap +! ;

What happens here is:
s" ..."  places two items on stack: address of first string character, and string length, which is 10 in this case. The sequence "swap +!"  adds string length, 10, to the contents at first string address, thereby changing ASCII H to ASCII R.

A version matching the requirements slightly better is compiled using vfx:

```
: h 1 s" Happy 2021" 2dup type + 1- c+! ;
```

reason for using a different compiler for this version is that it provides c+! already which I'd have to add to gforth first, which should introduce a penalty of about 22 chars.

disassembling first:

> ( 080C0AF0    E81383F9FF )            CALL      08058E08      (S") "Happy 2021"
> ( 080C0B00    8BD3 )                  MOV       EDX, EBX
> ( 080C0B02    035D00 )                ADD       EBX, [EBP]
> ( 080C0B05    4B )                    DEC       EBX
> ( 080C0B06    800301 )                ADD       Byte Ptr 0 [EBX], 01
> ( 080C0B09    8BDA )                  MOV       EBX, EDX
> ( 080C0B0B    FF15B9DE0408 )          CALL      [0804DEB9]      TYPE
> ( 080C0B11    C3 )                    NEXT,

executing several times, output follows immediately:

> h  Happy 2022
> h  Happy 2023
> h  Happy 2024
> h  Happy 2025
> h  Happy 2026

disassembling again:

> ( 080C0B30    E8D382F9FF )            CALL      08058E08        (S") "Happy 2026"
> ( 080C0B40    8BD3 )                  MOV       EDX, EBX
> ( 080C0B42    035D00 )                ADD       EBX, [EBP]
> ( 080C0B45    4B )                    DEC       EBX
> ( 080C0B46    800301 )                ADD       Byte Ptr 0 [EBX], 01
> ( 080C0B49    8BDA )                  MOV       EBX, EDX
> ( 080C0B4B    FF15B9DE0408 )          CALL      [0804DEB9]      TYPE
> ( 080C0B51    C3 )                    NEXT,

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: Thank you. I'm aware that this answer doesn't quite match the requirements. So I added the aspect of timelessness, for the years to come at least - After Rappy comes Sappy, then Tappy.  After that, wait to enjoy Wappy and Zappy.

Comment: And not to forget Yappy :)

Answer (score 1):

### Python (144 characters; 130 after removal of 10%)

This codes writes a library, thats imported (again after updating the code) and used.

```
import datetime
f=open("y.py",'w')
f.write("def year():return "+str(datetime.date.today().year))
f.close()
import y
print "Happy "+str(y.year())
```

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge 98, 26 bytes - 10% (bonus) = 23.4

```
"EMIT"4(Yd0p"  yppaH"5k,.@
```

The first space immediately after the quote gets overwritten with a unicode character with code point equal to the year.

The self-modifying part of this code actually makes it more verbose. The below code performs the same task without self-modification:

```
"EMIT"4(Y" yppaH"5k,.@
```

Answer (score 0):

## Racket - 139 - 10% = 125.1

```
(let g((y(date-year(seconds->date(current-seconds))))(h"Happy ~a~%"))
(if(< 2013 y)(begin(set! g(lambda()(printf h y)))(g))(printf h 2013)))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(let g ((y (date-year (seconds->date (current-seconds))))
        (h "Happy ~a~%"))
    (if (< 2013 y)
        (begin 
          (set! g (lambda () (printf h y)))
          (g))
        (printf h 2013)))
```

So I'm using a named `let` which is creating a procedure `g` and calling it with the parameter y (current year) and h (printf format string). If `y` is higher than 2013 i **redefine** `g` to a procedure that takes no arguments and prints a suitable string for the current year instead just before calling the new procedure. It's short since `h` and `y` are in the new procedures closure variables.

Comment: Not self-modifying.

Comment: @Tobia How about now?

Comment: IMHO you're still using an if that chooses between two code paths, you're not modifying the actual source code being run. See the PHP answer by @PleaseStand (the longer one) for an example of actual self-modifying code.

Comment: @Tobia According to the wikipedia page changing function pointers are considered self modifying. I change a two argument procedure to a zero argument procedure of one line after 2013. The PHP example doesn't change it's code but elements of it's data segment. In reality only machine code can alter itself and it needs a low security OS to do it.

Comment: I agree that the PHP example is only changing its data segment and not its bytecode, but I still think it's the most "self-modifying" code in all this page. Self modification is not restricted to machine code: interpreted languages can alter their source, bytecode, or whatever data structure is being traversed by the interpreter. This is not exposed by most interpreters, but it can be done through pointer manipulation or /proc/self/mem tricks, like in the PHP example. Still, my answer is not better than yours, so I might as well remove my downvote :)

Answer (score 0):

## Perl (100 characters (90 after removal of 10%))

```
$^I="";@ARGV=$0;s/ \K\d+/$l=(localtime)[5]+1900/e,print while<>;exec perl,$0if$&!=$l;print"Happy 1
"
```

It's probably too long, but I don't care (at least it's round in its size). Could be shorter if it would read UTC time (replace `localtime` with `gmtime`). Please note that after running, it will increase its size to 103 characters (unless you run this in year 10000, then 104 characters), but hey, it's self-modifying.

Answer (score -1):

### **Python 2,(151-10%)=136**

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057487/self-modifying-code/3057568#3057568)

```
from datetime import*
s=int(str(datetime.now())[:4]);x=2013;q=globals
def l(): return x
n="def l():return[x,s][s>x]"
exec(n,q(),q())
print'Happy %d'%l()
```

Comment: I wouldn't consider `exec` as self-modification, it's just part of the language.

Comment: @Tobia i have modified my answer please re-consider

Comment: I still think changing a function definition or using exec is not proper "self-modifying" code. But my answer is not better than yours, so I will remove my downvote.

Answer (score -1):

## JavaScript (ECMAScript 5)/HTML (HTML5) - 106

```
<script id=k type=x>2013</script><script>k.innerHTML=new Date().getFullYear();alert('Happy '+k.innerHTML);
```

And here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XAEQb/)

Note that in the jsfiddle, I included a closing `</script>`, but it isn't necessary, it is just necessary to work in jsfiddle

Comment: Are you sure? unclosed script tags don't work on my browsers.

Comment: The idea of using `innerHTML` to modify the source code is neat, but IMHO this is not self-modifying code, because the modified part does not actually execute. You just use `k.innerHTML` like any other string variable.

Comment: It doesn't say in the code anywhere that it needs to execute the code, it just needs to be self modifying. And this is.

Answer (score -1):

## Javascript 122 - 10% = 109.8

```
function n(){y=0;z=new Date().getFullYear();if(y-z){eval((""+n).replace(y,z));alert("Happy new "+z)}setTimeout(n,1000)}n()
```

It will greet you with a happy new year for the current year, and also keep checking periodically forever and greet you again if a new year comes.

Comment: Not self-modifying.

Answer (score -3):

## PHP, 28 (-10% is 25)

```
echo"Happy ".date('Y')."!";
```

Comment: How is this self-modifying?

Comment: Not self-modifying.

Answer (score -3):

### HTML/JavaScript - 63 (70-10%)

```
<body onload="b.innerHTML=new Date().getFullYear()">Happy <b id=b>2013
```

Comment: Not self-modifying.